# Maven Error in IDEA :Maven project configuration required for module 'quickStart' isn't available

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

- I create a maven project from archetype `org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart`,but keep getting this error every time I try to run the main method(just to print "hello world").

  **Error: Maven Resources Compiler: Maven project configuration required for module 'quickStart' isn't available. Compilation of Maven projects is supported only if external build is started from an IDE.**
- At first I assumed it's wrong with my maven 3.6.2 or jdk 1.8.0_241, so I used maven 3.5.2 and jdk 7 instead. I also tried some other methods to solve this problems like `rebuild the project` or `delete VM options for importer`, however, it still doesn't work.
- the version of IDEA is IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.4, I would appreciate it if anyone could help, THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Probably your Maven Settings in your project is not right, set the Maven home directory to the right path (see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven.html).

Comment: I spend the whole day to find a proper method to solve this problem within fewer steps, but now I give in to a one-step solution : reinstall IDEA 2019.3.1, it works again . **Thanks anyway!**

Answer (score 0):

I use Intellij IDEA. What I did to solve this issue is this: Open `pom.xml` then right click and choose 'Add as maven project'.